# variable href in cgi-bin

Tags: html, bash, cgi

I have a bash cgi script which runs some command and executable files and in the end it creates a result zip files in a new directory.
here is the bashcgi.sh file code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>'
echo '<html lang="en">'
echo '  <head> '
echo ' <h1><a href="/test/index.html">Test</a></h1>'
echo ' </head>
echo '<body>'
**my script and variables here**
echo 'Download the output files: '
echo '<a href="/var/htdocs/test/$variableOutput/output.zip">click here to download result</a><br> '
echo '</body>
echo '</html>
```

The above script file is located in "/var/cgi-bin/" and which there are many variables and creates an output folder inside var/htdocs/test/ the folder name changes according to user input (in previous php, the input name will be saved as a text file) 
Is there any way to give link to that variable folder in href? 
that is when users click on the link they should be redirected to the link with name of variable folder. ex if `$variableOutput = testresult1` they should redirect to  `/var/htdocs/test/testresult1/output.zip` .

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href=/var/htdocs/test/$variableOutput/output.zip>click here to download result</a><br>"
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.